# A Method with 2 Kind of Return Type

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

Ok, I have 3 classes: **Teacher**, **Student** and **Database** for that matter.  I wanna read data from database and put it in *Teacher* or **Student**. So i have to write something like this:

```
public Teacher dbSelect(string Table="Teacher")
{
    Table = char.ToUpper(Table[0]) + Table.Substring(1);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + ";";
    return dbConnect(query, true);
}
```

But i must have this exact Method with **Student** return:

```
public Student dbSelect(string Table="Student")
{
    Table = char.ToUpper(Table[0]) + Table.Substring(1);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + ";";
    return dbConnect(query, true);
}
```

Now I can write each one in their **ViewModel**, But I want to put them in **Database** class. So is there any way to do that?
(I know i can return them in a list and then work with that list, But just wanna know if there is a way or not!)

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to put *dbConnect* in here, so:

```
public List<Teacher> dbConnect(string query)
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = null;
        SQLiteCommand command = null;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = null;
        Teacher result = new Teacher(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            //    try
            {
                conn = new SQLiteConnection(db.db);
                conn.Open();
                command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            //   catch (Exception ex) { }
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Teacher temp = new Teacher(
                    reader[0].ToString(),    
                    reader[1].ToString(),                              
                    reader[2].ToString(),                              
                    reader[3].ToString(),                              
                    reader[4].ToString(), 
                    reader[5].ToString(),                              
                    reader[6].ToString(),                              
                    reader[7].ToString()                               
                    );
                result.Items.Add(temp);
            }
        conn.Close();
        return result.Items;
    }
```

And again the exact thing exist for **Student** but returning:

```
public List<Student> dbConnect(string query)
{
    ...
}
```

**Answer:** I had a **Base** class and of course wanted to return a **List** with a specific type, So I used **@Jauch** answer, but with returning the **List**.

Comment: Hi @Mostafa. A few thoughts.
1. Both routines will return the exactly same value, that is the value returned by dbConnect. 2. What is the relationship between the probably  READER that will be returned by cbConnect and Student/Teacher?

Comment: Hello @Jauch. One of the return Student, and another one return Teacher. Actually that's what i had to put in my question! :D. I'll be fixing it right now!

Comment: Ah... Much clearer now :)

Comment: I did something similar, but I used a system based on generics and interfaces. In order to "populate" the object (Teacher or Student, for example), that can have different columns/properties, I used reflection to match the columns in the reader with the properties in the object.

Comment: If you could give me an example, It would be great. Because I don't know how they work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea on how to do what you want, adapted from a code of mine:

```
public class BaseClass<T> 
    where T : new ()
{
    protected List<object> list;
    protected string query;
    protected PropertyInfo[] fProperties;
    protected Assembly fStoreAssembly;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
        fStoreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly (typeof(T));
        fProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = null;
        SQLiteCommand command = null;
        SQLiteDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(db.db);
            conn.Open();
            command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            StoreResults (reader);

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            //deal with the exception here
        }
    }

    //Store results walks through all the records returned and 
    //creates new instances of the store object and saves in the list,
    //using reflection
    protected void StoreResults (SQLiteDataReader reader)
    {
        if (fProperties == null)
            throw new Exception ("Store type definition is missing");

        while (reader.Read ())
        {                
            object newStoreItem = fStoreAssembly.CreateInstance (typeof(T).FullName);                
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in fProperties)
            {
                string lcName = pi.Name.ToLower ();

                if (HasColumn(reader, lcName))
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(lcName)))
                        pi.SetValue(newStoreItem, reader[lcName], null);                    
                }
            }

            list.Add (newStoreItem);
        }
    }

    public bool HasColumn (SQLiteDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
        {
            if (row ["ColumnName"].ToString () == columnName)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here how you would create Teacher and Student

```
public class TeacherInfo
{
    //Properties for store info from database
}

public class Teacher : BaseClass<TeacherInfo>
{
     public Teacher ()
         : BaseClass()
     {
         query = "whatever you want here"
     }             
}

public class StudentInfo
{
    //Properties for store info from database
}

public class Student : BaseClass<StudentInfo>
{
     public Student ()
         : BaseClass()
     {
         query = "whatever you want here";
     }

}
```

As the Read routine is public, you can call Read from any instance of Teacher or Student.
You can even create them and store as BaseClass and use it directly if you don't need to know if it is a student or a teacher (for common routines, etc)

This is not an extensive example, but just a point in the direction you could use to turn your code more generic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is all new to me :D, so I have to work on it for now.

Comment: @Mostafa, hope it helps. I suggest you to study generics, interfaces and reflection :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the semantics of using interfaces to return the values and then cast the return type to an appropriate one, or use a base class (interfaces would be better, as you can still extend other classes as base classes while implementing the interface). The entity interface can be created as following,

```
public interface SchoolEntity { 
    // Provide the similar properties as members of this interface.
}
```

Then you can implement this interface in your `Teacher` and `Student`.

```
public class Student : SchoolEntity { }
public class Teacher : SchoolEntity { }
```

Finally, the parameter can be made a bit more clearer by using enumerations. They would be more clearer while reading, rather than having the same parameter types. *Note that function overloading doesn't consider return type as a signature difference*.

```
enum Entity { Teacher, Student }
```

And then you can check which data to return.

```
public SchoolEntity dbSelect(Entity type)
{
    switch(type) {
         case Teacher:
             var query = "SELECT * FROM Teacher";
             return dbConnect(query, true);
         // Rest of the cases.
    }
}
```

Note that, your SQL statement is open to SQL Injection and anyone can either drop the tables, or perform actions that can be passed to the engine.

#### Working in a list

Working with the list won't be a good idea. Afterall, what list would you return? Would that be, `public List<Teacher> dbSelect` or `public List<Student> dbSelect`? The answer and solution to this is to have a same type backing up these both types.

#### `dbSelect` function

Note that you are still returning only `Teacher` type, then why you are having a Student at all? You should definitely cast it back. As a matter of fact, if I had to develop this. I would have to the `dbSelect` function to take the `Entity` as a parameter to keep all of the database requests and processing in a single function.

```
public List<Teacher> dbConnect(Entity type)
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = null;
    SQLiteCommand command = null;
    SQLiteDataReader reader = null;
    Teacher result = null; // Can be set to null.
        //    try
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(db.db);
            conn.Open();
            string query;

            // This way, leave the function to build the query.
            if(type == Entity.Teacher) {
                query = "SELECT * FROM Teacher";
            } else {
                query = "SELECT * FROM Student";
            }
            command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        //   catch (Exception ex) { }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(type == Entity.Teacher) {
                Teacher temp = new Teacher(
                    reader[0].ToString(),    
                    reader[1].ToString(),                              
                    reader[2].ToString(),                              
                    reader[3].ToString(),                              
                    reader[4].ToString(), 
                    reader[5].ToString(),                              
                    reader[6].ToString(),                              
                    reader[7].ToString()                               
                );
                result.Items.Add(temp);
            } else {
                // Add the student.
            }
        }
    conn.Close();
    return result;
}
```

Now in this code, you are aware `result` is of type `Teacher`. There was no list there and this made your code a bit confusing. Take my advice: Re-write the code.

Please also go through the following useful links:

[Explicit Interface Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
[Signatures and overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But dbConnect type for **Teacher** is `List<Teacher>` and for **Student** is `List<Student>`. As your first solution, I can't understand how **dbSelect** could return both `List<Teacher>` and `List<Student>`. If you could explain a little more, I appreciate it. *Note: Thanks for letting me know about SQL Injection.*

Comment: @Mostafa, it will not. It will return `List<SchoolEntity>`, and you can cast it to either `Teacher` or `Student` later. That is the usage of having to implement interfaces or base classes.

Comment: As I know about Interfaces, I have to declare members properties' in SchoolEntity (As you said), but properties of Teacher are different from Student, For example one have password but the other has not. So how can I use it in that matter?